# Error in R: Error in UseMethod("group_by_")

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to group the following variable:

```
Total_household <- data %>% group_by(HOUSEHOLD) %>%
summarize(area = sum(AREA))
```

I got this error message:

> Error in UseMethod("group_by_") :    no applicable method for
>   'group_by_' applied to an object of class "function"

It first worked and after a while i got the error message. How can this!

Comment: `data` is a base R  function.  Are you sure you assigned it as the name of your data?

Comment: See [mcve] regarding how to ask a question on SO.

Comment: @RichScriven, my data name is actually dataset1, should that matter? it is strange that i used the name data before and it works fine, but after a while not anymore.